# How to search for values of several columns at once that start with some string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I completely new to the world of databases and querying.

I have the following db

[image: db]

for which I want to construct a "smart" search query for to be able to fetch relevant entries based on a query that looks for something in the `isbn`, `name` and `author` columns.  The catch is that the input query doesn't necessarily have to be a keyword, it can be part of one. I want to be able to enter a part of an isbn number, a part of a book's name, a part of an author's name and get back relevant results.

Say I query for "97182", I want all the books whose isbn begins with that sequence.

Or if I query "ma", I want all the entries whose name or author begins with "ma".

For example I recently learned that one could do the following (I believe the name is "full text search") using Postgresql:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE to_tsvector(isbn || ' ' || name || ' ' || author) @@ to_tsquery('proust')
```

Output will be the rows that have "proust" in one of the searched for columns.

[image: output]

The same postgresql query will not work for what I mentioned due to the nature of how it works (vectorizing columns, reducing to lexemes etc.). I have not fully understood full text search yet though.

Is it possible to create a "smarter" query according to my description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE LOWER(isbn || ' ' || name || ' ' || author) LIKE '%proust%'
```

Unlike the proprietary functions you used, this code will run on all RDBMS.

Comment: Is this native SQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @NoName123 It’s standard SQL.